# Linear Algebra Matrix Question solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Hi I was just wondering if an augmented matrix had no pivot positions, would the system have infinite solutions? Since it has no pivot positions that means, the columns must be filled with 0s and it is an empty matrix. That is only one solution correct?

Answer (score 0):

If the augmented matrix is a zero matrix then there are infinitely many solutions as any arbitrarily chosen values of the variables is a solution. You just need to remember that a solution is defined to be a collection of values which satisfies the system of equations. In this case the system is $0\vec{x}=0$ which is trivially satisfied by any $\vec x$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean what I think you mean, you're correct.  If the augmented matrix corresponding to the system $Ax = b$ has no pivots, then $A$ and $b$ must both be zero.  That is, in order to get such an augmented matrix, we must have started with the system
$$
\pmatrix{
0&\cdots&0\\
\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
0&\cdots&0}
\vec x = 
\pmatrix{0\\\vdots\\0
}
$$
Since this equality holds for any $\vec x$, the solution is "all $\vec x$", which is (in most contexts) infinite.

Comment: thanks for the answer, you mentioned (in most contexts). Is there an example in which it is not infinite

Comment: @user123204: If you are working in a finite ring/field.

Comment: Sure! Usually, we talk about vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$; that is, the entries of matrices are usually real  (or complex) numbers.  We could, however, have matrices with entries in any field, which includes [finite fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)#Finite_fields).